# How to create a java grid slider?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, menu, gridpanel

i am having bit a trouble creating a dynamic grid menu. i want to load items from my stock in mysql database and display in a grid menu. i usually use a jtable here is what i want[image]

this is what i did with my code

```
   void GridTest() {
       for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(i + 1));
            jPanel1.add(button);
           button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(getTitle());
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

when i click left or right should go to the next 12 items. is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Yes, but all the details will depend on your implementation. You should have a model of some kind,,which allows you to "page" through the results, which notifies the ui that it needs to update its view. The model would control which values are currently available. Assuming your ResultSet supports cursors, your could simply back the model with the result set and move the cursor by the appropriate amount. I'd not recreate the buttons on each page change, I'd just update there contents

Answer (score 0):

This should be done with a LayoutManager.

Use a JPanel to hold more JPanels - these JPanels should hold the buttons that hold each "grid".

Assign a `CardLayout` as the LayoutManager for the panel holder. Therefore, you can do this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    ((CardLayout) container.getLayout()).show(container, "panel_name");
                }
            });
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is a section of the Java Tutorial for dealing with Card Layouts.

Comment: So , you're suggesting the op load ALL the view/pages? That's a lot, it would be simpler to use a single view and update its contents based on the current page - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer Maybe... Not sure though about that. I tend to use CardLayouts extensively in my code... :/

Comment: Imagin you had 12, 000 products, that's 1, 000 views you have to create. While from a coding point of view, that's probably no hard, you could do the same thing with a single view and simple model, just saying ;)

Comment: No I definitely see what you're saying :D but for something such a small scale I don't see a complete need for something like that

Comment: How do you know what the scale is?  That then means that your solution won't scale over time and the OP will be stuck with a new problem

Comment: yeah it could be a huge no of items... so wht's best for me?